# Is there any performance benefit for `useSelector` by using together both a memoizing selector AND an equality comparison function?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I have the following logic in my **List** component:

```
const List = React.memo(() => {
    const apples = useSelector(
        (state) => Object.values(state.apples),
        (currentState, prevState) => currentState.length === prevState.length,
    );

  return 'whatever';
);
```

This gives me great results in terms of rendering times -> it renders only once and re-renders ONLY when the length of the "apples" changes, but NOT when the properties of the apples change.

However, I was wondering if adding a [memoized selector](https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks#using-memoizing-selectors) will result any performance benefit?

To illustrate my example:

```
const applesSelector = createSelector(
    (state) => Object.values(state.apples)
)

const List = React.memo(() => {
    const apples = useSelector(
        applesSelector,
        (currentState, prevState) => currentState.length === prevState.length,
    );

  return 'whatever';
);
```

So I struggle to find is there is a performance benefit for the `useSelector` by using together both a memoizing selector AND an equality comparison function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the example implementation of `applesSelector` there appears to be buggy.  The correct implementation would be:

```js
const applesSelector = createSelector(
  state => state.apples,
  apples => Object.values(apples)
)
```

That way, the output selector really only runs when `state.apples` has changed.

For your actual question: if you're using a memoizing selector, there shouldn't generally be a need to add an equality comparison argument to `useSelector`, because the work of doing the comparison has already happened internal to the selector function.

Comment: Thanks for your input! Still - in my example maybe there is a need to use both: 1) selector - runs when state.apples has changed (even if an attribute of a single apple item changed); 2) comparison -> restricts it to run only when array length is different. What do you think?

Comment: If you really only want it to run when the number of items has changed, then yeah, the equality check might be necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Memoization is something that is nice in reselect but the main benefit you get is composable selectors. Instead of answering 2 questions in 1 selector (where are apples and in what shape do I return them) you can answer one question in one selector "where are the apples" in selectAppes and "in what shape do I return them" as selectApplesAsArray that uses selectApples to get the apples. This prevents duplicate implementation.

The apples example is somewhat simple but a react application can have complex business rules in the selectors that you don't want to repeat. Something like selectPolicyPrice may need to re use other selectors to prevent duplication of implementation that would cause hard to fix bugs when the rules of policy pricing change.

Sometimes you may want to memoize array results such as when you do Object.keys, Object.values or Array.prototype.filter.

```js
const { createSelector, defaultMemoize } = Reselect;

const createMemArray = () => {
  const memArr = defaultMemoize((...arr) => arr);
  return (arr) => memArr(...arr);
};
const selectApples = (state) => state.apples;
const selectApplesAsArray = ((
  mem //mem will memoize array
) =>
  createSelector([selectApples], (apples) =>
    mem(Object.values(apples))//memoize each item in apples
  ))(createMemArray()); //IIFE createing memoized array

const state = { apples: { a: 1, b: 2 } };
const a = selectApplesAsArray(state),
  b = selectApplesAsArray({
    ...state,
    //copied, will not recalculate because of memoize array
    apples:{...state.apples},
    irrelevantChange: 22,
  });
console.log('a is b:', a === b);
console.log('a and b are:', a);
const c = selectApplesAsArray({
  ...state,
  apples: { ...state.apples, b: 'changed' },
});
console.log('c is b:', c === b);
console.log('c is:', c);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>


<div id="root"></div>
```

I wrote some [short examples](https://github.com/amsterdamharu/selectors) how selectors can be used with redux that may be helpful.